# How do I solve a "cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/kafka' " error in ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer, ballerina-vscode-plugin, ballerina-http, ballerina-kafka

I'm trying to import ballerinax/kafka so I can solve a kafka assignment but when I type it out, it gives me an error that says cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/kafka'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try building your code with `bal build`. It should pull `ballerinax/kafka` from the repository.